# Trouble Serializing Enum in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, enums

I have an elementary stumper using serialization in an ASP.NET 2.0 application on a C# class containing an enum property.  It's my understanding that serialization of enumerations is supported if they map to integers.  So, I can't figure out why I'm having this problem serializing/deserializing my enum.

**My Code:**

```
[Serializable]
public class Report
{
    public PercentTime paramPercentRange;

    // Constructors
    public Report()
    {
    }
    public Report(PercentTime percentRange)
    {
        paramPercentRange = percentRange;
    }
}

public enum PercentTime
{
    Null = 0,
    ZeroToFivePercent = 1,
    FiveToTenPercent = 2,
    TenToFifteenPercent = 3,
    FifteenToTwentyPercent = 4,
    MoreThanTwentyPercent = 5
}

// Serialize Report to a HiddenField
public void SaveReportObject(Report reportObj, HiddenField hiddenReportObj)
{
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();

    // Seralize Report Object to Binary Format
    formatter.Serialize(stream, reportObj);
    stream.Position = 0;

    // Convert Stream to ASCII Encoding
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII);

    // Store Report Object as a Base64 Encoded String in a HiddenField
    hiddenReportObj.Value = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd()));

    // Close Streams
    reader.Close();
    stream.Close();
}

public Report GetReportObject(String strBase64)
{
    Report report;
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII);
    writer.AutoFlush = true;
    stream.Position = 0;

    // Convert Base64 String to ASCII encoded Stream
    writer.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(strBase64)));
    stream.Position = 0;

    // Deserialze ASCII encoded Stream
    report = (Report)formatter.Deserialize(stream);  // error 

    // Close Streams
    writer.Close();
    stream.Close();

    return report;
}
```

**I get the following Invalid BinaryFormatter Error:**

```
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SizedArray.IncreaseCapacity(Int32 index)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SizedArray.set_Item(Int32 index, Object value)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Pages_Reports_PercentTimeLobbyingReport.GetReportObject(String strBase64)
```

When I look at the stream object, it's length is 287 but the position is 282.  My first guess is that it's a problem with not reading the entire stream, but I am able to change the Report class to store the enum as an integer and it works fine.  I'm very interested in learning what the problem is here.

Comment: Thanks for the stack trace, but what was the _exception_? Post the result of `ex.ToString()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your stream contains *binary* data. You're then converting that into *ASCII*. This is a really, really bad idea. You'll lose data. Don't do that.

You're doing base64 encoding, but in the wrong place. You should be converting the *originally written binary data* into base64, e.g. like this:

```
string text = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
```

Then to deserialize, you'd convert it the other way round:

```
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(text))
{
    return (Report)formatter.Deserialize(stream); 
}
```

I don't know why it was working for you when you were using an `int`... but my guess is that was more by luck than anything else.

You should never try reading the output of a `BinaryFormatter` as if it was just plain text.

Comment: I rebuilt with your suggested changes and viola no error! Jon, you are the man!